# mqtt: net.createConnection is not a function

Tags: typescript, react-native, mqtt

I am following this guide: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mqtt#install and to try to get an mqtt connection, but I am getting a render error saying
`_$$_REQUIRE_(dependencyMap[1], "net").createConnection(port, host)','_$$_REQUIRE(_dependencyMap[1], "net").createConnection' is undefined)`
[image: I attached a picture of the actual error]

Here is my app.tsx file (the only code that I actually wrote):

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableOpacity, Dimensions } from 'react-native';
import { connect } from 'mqtt';
import { Buffer } from "buffer"

export default function App() {
  console.log("START")

var client  = connect('mqtt://localhost:1883')

client.on('connect', function () {
  console.log("Connected")
  client.subscribe('presence', function (err : any) {
    if (!err) {
      client.publish('presence', 'Hello mqtt')
    }
  })
})

client.on('message', function (topic : any, message : any) {
  // message is Buffer
  console.log(message.toString())
  client.end()
})

  return (
    <View style = {{flex : 1}}>
      <View style = {{flex : 1}}>
      </View>

      <View style = {{justifyContent:'center', alignItems:'center',alignSelf:'center', position:'absolute'}}>
        <View 
          style={{backgroundColor:'rgba(255,0,0,' + 1 + ')', 
                height:Dimensions.get('window').height + 100, 
                width:Dimensions.get('window').width}}>
        </View>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: use react-native-native-mqtt , https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-native-mqtt

Answer (score 4):

[mqtt.js](https://github.com/mqttjs/MQTT.js) is written for "for node.js and the browser" and, as discussed in [this issue](https://github.com/mqttjs/MQTT.js/issues/573), there are a range of challenges using it with react native. I'd suggest that you refer to that issue for guidance (using [a fork](https://github.com/mqttjs/MQTT.js/issues/573) appears to work for some but there are a [number of other packages available](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=mqtt%20react%20native&ranking=popularity)).

Anyway your specific question relates to the `net.createConnection is not a function` error so I'll address that.

In order to connect to an MQTT broker directly over TCP (e.g. `mqtt://localhost:1883`) the library uses the [node.js net api](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html). This does not work in browsers because they do not permit direct TCP connections. The work around is to use websockets (e.g. 'ws://localhost:8080') however this will only work if your broker supports websockets and is correctly configured ([example code](https://github.com/mqttjs/MQTT.js/blob/master/examples/ws/client.js)).

React native applications are not constrained by the restrictions imposed by a browser but the `net` API is not available out of the box which is why you are seeing the error. Possible workarounds include:

- Use websockets
- Use a library that provides the `net` api (e.g. [this](https://github.com/Rapsssito/react-native-tcp-socket) or [this](https://github.com/aprock/react-native-tcp/))

Note that rather than attempting either option I'd recommend referring to the [issue noted](https://github.com/mqttjs/MQTT.js/issues/573) above (you are likely to run into other problems).